# stackapps favicon inconsistent rendering

Tags: support, status-completed, icons

A lot of us are using the favicon in our apps as it is a quite convenient size.

It seems that IE does not like the stackapps favicon palette and renders the background black.

While I do cache the icons on my server and *could* fix it and not update it, it might be nice if this could be fixed upstream.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed.

Mind, anyone who already has the favicon cached naturally won't see it until it falls out of their local cache.

Comment: Cache... what's that? - Just kidding :)

Comment: @George - more concerned about browsers than [app]s.  favicon is an unusual beast, and we can't explicit cache break it.